# Sticking a label in top right corner of Tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on creating a Tkinter planner application that has multiple pages. On the start page, you can enter a date in the calendar and press the 'enter' button to enter the application.

The home page then displays the date in the top right corner. Is there any way for the date label to overlap with the blue banner so that there isn't a grey line at the top? The date also needs to be placed so that it stays in the same spot even when the window is resized, hence why I have used the pack function. However, I believe that the pack function cannot overlap with other labels.

[image]

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import *
from datetime import datetime


 #calendar and display in label

#window = Tk()

#window.title("StudyFriendO")

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 24)

class StudyFriendO(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("StudyFriendO") #naming window title
        self.geometry('850x830') #size of window




        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, HomePage, ToDoPage, TimetablePage): #list of multiple frames of program

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def set_date(self, cont):
        #frame: StartPage = self.frames[cont]
        #frame.date_label.config(text="Today's date is " + datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")) #function to get date from
        frame2: HomePage = self.frames[HomePage]
        frame2.date_label.config(text= datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")) #function to get date from




class StartPage(tk.Frame): #creating start page

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)







        label = tk.Label(self, text="StudyFriendO", font = LARGE_FONT, bg="#f2fcff")
        label.pack(fill="x")

        #place(x=315,y=100)

        photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file=image file) #photo1 is a variable
        #label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        panel = tk.Label(self, image = photo1)
        panel.image = photo1
        panel.pack(fill="x")

        #place(x=270,y=150)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Enter today's date and your first name below:", bg="#f2fcff")
        label2.pack(fill="x", ipady=20)

        #place(x=305, y=400)


        cal = Calendar(self, background="#e0f6fc", disabledbackground="white", bordercolor="light blue", headersbackground="light blue", normalbackground="#e0f6fc", foreground="black", normalforeground='black', headersforeground='white', selectmode="day", year=2021, month=8, day=9)
        cal.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
        #(x=300,y=430) #calendar

        nameentry = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white") #text input for users name
        nameentry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.68, anchor='center')
        #(x=365, y=635)

        caldate = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                            command=lambda: controller.set_date(StartPage)) #button to get current date
        caldate.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.63, anchor='center')

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Enter",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.73, anchor='center')
        #(x=387,y=660)

        #self.date_label = tk.Label(self, text="") #label to display date
        #self.date_label.pack(pady=20)

        self.configure(bg='#f2fcff')


class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font = LARGE_FONT)
        #label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.date_label = tk.Label(self, text="") #label to display date
        self.date_label.pack(side='top', anchor='ne')

        #width of x
        tk.Label(self, text ="Name's Planner", fg="white", bg="#c0e3ed", font = LARGE_FONT).pack(fill="x", ipady=30)



        #height of Y
        tk.Label(self, text="", fg="white", bg="#99cbd8").pack(side="left", fill="y", ipadx=73)
    
        button1 = tk.Button(self, height=2, width=10, bg="#e0f6fc", text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(x=35, y=145)
        
        button1 = tk.Button(self, height=2, width=10, bg="#e0f6fc", text="To Do", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(x=35, y=225)
        #(relx=0.2, rely=0.4, anchor='center')

        button1 = tk.Button(self, height=2, width=10, bg="#e0f6fc", text="Timetable", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(x=35, y=305)

        photo2 = tk.PhotoImage(image file) #photo1 is a variable
        #label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        panel = tk.Label(self, image = photo2)
        panel.image = photo2
        panel.place(x=35, y=400)

        self.configure(bg='#f7f6f6')




class ToDoPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="To Do", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Timetable",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Do",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()


class TimetablePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Timetable", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Timetable",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Do",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

app = StudyFriendO()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: But I can say that as you said the pack function cannot overlap with other labels so there are two possible solutions: 1 - use place and update de position with a bind method when the window is resized or 2 - you can make the blue banner as a Frame, not a Label with two labels inside: one for the date (initially blank) and another for the title. After setting the date you just change the date label text

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.place()` instead of `.pack()`, but better create and place it after the banner:

```py
...
        tk.Label(self, text ="Name's Planner", fg="white", bg="#c0e3ed", font = LARGE_FONT).pack(fill="x", ipady=30)

        #label to display date with same background color of the above banner
        self.date_label = tk.Label(self, text="", bg="#c0e3ed") 
        # keep placing the label at top right corner
        self.date_label.place(relx=1, y=0, anchor='ne')
...
```